# grep command not working with xargs and pipe usage

Tags: grep

I am trying to list hijacked files using `cleartool ls -recurse` commands which seems not to work when symbolic links are present.

So trying to do something like below:

```
find -L -type f -print0 | xargs -0 cleartool ls
```

Which prints the `cleartool ls` output for each file as expected, but when I grep for "hijacked" it fails:

```
find -L -type f -print0 | xargs -0 cleartool ls | grep -i hijacked
```

It outputs nothing though there are hijacked files.

Comment: You can try: `find -L -type f -print0 | xargs -0 cleartool ls 2>&1 | grep -i hijacked` to redirect stderr to stdout.